# How to setup Netbeans IDE to debug Maven JavaFx project on Raspberry remotely?

Tags: maven, javafx, netbeans, raspberry-pi, remote-debugging

I want to debug and run my Maven JavaFx project on Raspberry pi 3B+ from my workstation. I've tried Maven with Standard Java application and JavaFx application without Maven, in both situation it works successfully. But when I try with JavaFx Maven it gives me an error.

I've use **"ssh-exec-maven-plugin"** plugin with Maven Java Application and it works.
If Maven not used, both Java application and JavaFx can be remotely run with Netbeans Remote Runtime Platform. When I tried **"ssh-exec-maven-plugin"** plugin with Maven JavaFx project it gives me an error

> Failed to execute goal org.rogueware.mojo:ssh-exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (default-cli) on project mavenproject1: Execution default-cli of goal org.rogueware.mojo:ssh-exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]

Resources that I've use,

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1049839&sid=37a34bec94c20b0febe687740aba2488#p1049839
- http://artem.gratchev.com/2015/03/java-application-jar-raspberry-pi-maven-eclipse/

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.erenay</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mavenproject1</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>com.erenay.mavenproject1.MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>Your Organisation</name>
    </organization>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- PART I ADD -->
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.rogueware.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>ssh-exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <configuration>

                    <sshHost>10.0.0.124</sshHost>
                    <sshUsername>pi</sshUsername>
                    <sshPassword>123456</sshPassword>
                    <remoteExecutable>export DISPLAY=:0.0;java</remoteExecutable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- END of PART I ADD -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>                            
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>  
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Also Project Properties->Actions->Run Project and Debug Project->Execute Goals
are replaced by **clean package org.rogueware.mojo:ssh-exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec**

Thanks.

Comment: org.rogueware.mojo is not a plugin, ssh-exec-maven-plugin is. And the latest version seems to be 1.2 while you are using 1.0.

Comment: Thanks I tried with 1.2 and nothing changed